# Wrap stdout of command in bash

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

After running a command, I want the stdout of that command to be delimited like so:

```
/home/myUser
$ echo output of command `history 1 | cut -d ' ' -f 1`
begin command number 501
  output of command 501
end command number 501
/home/myUser
$ ...
```

currently, I'm doing this by setting `prompt_command` to do `echo end $histnum` before displaying the prompt, but I'm not sure how to get the `begin` line or how to ensure the stdout of the command is kept apart from from other terminal output that happens to occur at the same time (for example, a coproc that ends)

Is this possible?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're hoping to do... can you revise your example to be more explicit? Are the `501` and `502` at the end of the lines relevant? If so, what are they?

Comment: they're not really relevant. in this case they're the history number of the command being executed, but that's the easy part, the part I'm having trouble with is making everything appear in the right position

Comment: Do you really want to indent the output of each command? I'd also encourage you to adjust this strategy in light of UNIX pipelines -- you don't want to execute `cat /some/file | grep command` and incorrectly match your wrapping text. Perhaps the begin/end text could be sent to a different fd? Or written to a separate file?

Comment: indenting would be nice but I don't mind going without it. Yeah, exactly, I want to keep the "display" text from the shell itself (including the prompt text being discussed now and also other text like you get when a background process ends) separate from the output of the command. I want to do that, but I don't know how, and how to make it display even when written to a different fd. Maybe echo to the fd of the shell itself? But that's what I'm asking